# Having trouble selecting some specific xpath... (html table, scrapy, xpath)

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data (using scrapy) from tables that can be found here:

http://www.bettingtools.co.uk/tipster-table/tipsters

My spider functions when I parse response within the following xpath:
`//*[@id="imagetable"]/tbody/tr`

Every table on the page shares that id, so I'm basically grabbing all the table data.

However, I only want the table data for the current month (tables in the right column).

When I try and be more specific with my xpath, I get an invalid xpath error even though it seems to be correct. I've tried:

```
 - //*[@id="content"]/[contains(@class, "column2")]/[contains(@class, "table3")]/[@id="imagetable"]/tbody/tr
 - //*[@id="content"]/div[contains(@class, "column2")]/div[contains(@class, "table3")]/[@id="imagetable"]/tbody/tr
 - //*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[1]/[@id="imagetable"]/tbody/tr
```

Also, when I try to select the xpath of a specific table on the page with chrome I just get `//*[@id="imagetable"].`

Am I missing something obvious here? Why are the 3 above xpath examples I've tried not valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes those 3 invalid xpath is the part with this pattern :

```
/[predicate expression here]
```

above xpath missed to select a node on which the predicate would be applied. It should rather looks like this :

```
/*[predicate expression here]
```

Here are some examples of valid ones :

```
1. /table[@id="imagetable"]
2. /div[contains(@class, "column2")]
3. /*[contains(@class, "table3")]
```

For this specific task, you can try the following xpath which selects rows from `table` inside `<div class="column2">` :

```
//div[@class='column2']//table[@id="imagetable"]/tbody/tr
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my anwser [Selenium automation- finding best xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933442/selenium-automation-finding-best-xpath/23934039#23934039). In short check it by browser, browser can give U unique locator, then check it.